# Are update cascades only used for denormalized tables?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, rdbms

I'm just reading up on update cascading, and I was wondering if this is only for denormalized tables, for status and type fields?  Seems like normalization would remove the need for this, but I just wanted to confirm or learn about other useful reasons for update cascading.  Thx!

Comment: I suspect your understanding of "denormalized" is a little wonky. Arguably, the higher the normal form, the *more* likely it is that update cascading would be useful.

Comment: @onedaywhen, appreciate the response and your time.  I'm sure my understanding of denormalized is wonky, as I'm definitely a novice with DB design.  I mostly look at it as having all data be atomic, which is clearly oversimplified, but originally made me question the need for update cascades.  Are there any situations other than when PK's need to be modified or merged between two or more sources?

Comment: Hard to respond to because I don't you what you've misunderstood "denormalized" to mean :) I think the 'merging' scenario @Michael is imagining is a little contrived: `INTEGER` is unsuitable for `order_number`and not just for the one reason given (analyse what real online retailers use) and we can reasonably assume `order_number` values for past orders will never change even when enterprises merge (what would the auditor say?!)...

Comment: ...Instead, consider a key based on attributes assumed to be stable, though not necessarily immutable. Off the top of my head, a `SalaryHistory` table with a key on the compound of `(employee_number, start_date)` where in some circumstances `start_date` may change (pay raise back dated on appeal or whatever).

Answer (score 5):

It is necessary and useful for normalized tables, to enforce the foreign key relationships between them.  It's  somewhat rarer that you would change the value of a PK field, particularly if it's `auto_increment`, but when it happens, the change cascades down through the normalized FK relationships.

Likewise, `ON UPDATE DELETE` is useful to cascade row deletions through all your `1:1` FK relationships making it unnecessary to perform multiple deletes from application code.  It can be error-prone to do so anyway.

Consider the following:

```
table customers:
custid INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
custname VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL

table orders:
orderid INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
custid INT NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (custid) REFERENCES customers (custid) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Suppose you need to merge records from two databases, but this would cause PK collisions.  You can now safely update all the PK `custid` in `customers` in one of the databases and all associated orders automatically are reassociated with the new ids.

Comment: ah gotcha, I didn't think of merging records, that makes a lot of sense.  Thx for your insight, really appreciate it!

Comment: The usefulness of `ON UPDATE DELETE` is not limited to 1:1 relationships :)

Answer (score 4):

Update cascades can also be used to maintain referential integrity. This is primarily useful when the parent table's primary key is not an autoincremented identity value.

Comment: that's a good point.  I didn't think of that as all of my tables have AI PK's.  Thx for replying, I appreciate it!